# Does mercurial automatically commit tags?

Tags: mercurial

When I do `hg tag example` is the tag automatically committed in the process?

Comment: Just try it out in a new repository. The necessary commands are actually a tiny bit shorter than your question: `hg init test; cd test; echo a > a.txt; hg commit -A -m a; hg tag X; hg log` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag is indeed committed but it's not automatically pushed.
so you will still have to do a `hg push` after it
check your output with the command `hg out`

Comment: Also remember that if you have uncommited changes, the tag will not represent them. So you have to commit your changes, then tag.